What is the order of $\text{Ker}(\hat{f})$ when order of annihilator of $\text{Ker}f$ is given?
Let $A,B$ be an abelian group. $\hat{A}=\text{Hom}(A,\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$,.
Let $f$ be a map $ f : A\to B$, and $\hat{f}:  \hat{B}\to \hat{A}$ be dual of $f$.
In general, $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ is the annihilator of $\mathrm{Ker}(\hat f)$.
In other words,
$\mathrm{Im}(f)=\{b \in B, \forall \lambda \in \mathrm{Ker}(\hat f), \lambda(b)= 0\}$.
Then, when order of $\text{Im}f$ is $n$, what is the order of $\text{Ker}(\hat{f})$ ?
$\text{Ker}(\hat{f})$ is annihilator of finite group $\text{Im}f$, that is, $0$ ? But in my text states the order is $n$ in specific case.

Didn't your other question claim that the image is the annihilator? So they have the same order?

@red_trumpet Sorry, it was typo. What I wanted to know was $\text{Ker}(\hat{f})$.

@red_trumpet Thank you for your comment. I modified question.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}$In general, $\Ker(\hat f)$ need not have the same order as $\Im(f)$. First note that for $A = \mathbb Z / n$ you have $\hat A \cong \mathbb Z/n$, which is generated by the mapping
$$\lambda: [k] \mapsto [k/n].$$
Now consider for example the surjection $$f: \mathbb Z/4 \to \mathbb Z/2, \quad[k] \mapsto [k \mod 2].$$
Dual to this map is the map
$$\hat f: \mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z/4, \quad [1] \mapsto [2],$$
which is injective, so $\Ker(\hat f) = 0$. But if you dualize again, you get back the original map $f = \hat{\hat f}$. So now indeed,
$$| \Ker(\hat{\hat f})| = |\Im(\hat f)|.$$

Is it impossible to know the order of $\text{Ker}(\hat{f})$  using $\text{Im}(\text{f})$ in general ?
